# How to discover to which table\field is linked the foreign key of a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms, database

I am pretty new in Microsoft **SQL server** and I am not much into databases.

I have the following doubt:

On my database I have a table named **CPE**

This table have a field (a column) named **SourceId** that is the **FOREIGN KEY** of my table.

So I think that this field have to contain the value definied in some field of another table because it binds together 2 tables).

What have I to do to discover what is the other field and the other table which is linked to?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: try using `select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for certainly:

```
sp_help [table_name]
```

or try this query:

```
select t.name as ForeignKeytable, fk.constraint_column_id as ForeignKey_No, c.name as ForeignKeyColumn 
from sys.foreign_key_columns as fk
inner join sys.tables as t on fk.parent_object_id = t.object_id
inner join sys.columns as c on fk.parent_object_id = c.object_id and fk.parent_column_id = c.column_id
where fk.referenced_object_id = (select object_id from sys.tables where name = 'name')
order by ForeignKeytable, ForeignKey_No
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Method 1 :**

```
SELECT
  object_name(parent_object_id) ParentTableName,
  object_name(referenced_object_id) RefTableName,
  name 
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE parent_object_id = object_id('Tablename')
```

Or:

**Method 2 :**

```
SELECT 
   OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) TableName,
   COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id,fc.parent_column_id) ColName
FROM 
   sys.foreign_keys AS f
INNER JOIN 
   sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc 
      ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
INNER JOIN 
   sys.tables t 
      ON t.OBJECT_ID = fc.referenced_object_id
WHERE 
   OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) = 'Tablename'
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Object Explorer**, right-click the table that will be on the foreign-key side of the relationship and click **Design**.
The table opens in **Table Designer**.

From the **Table Designer** menu, click **Relationships**.

The relationship appears in the **Selected Relationship** list with a system-provided name in the format FK__, where tablename is the name of the foreign key table.

Click the relationship in the **Selected Relationship** list.

Click **Tables** and **Columns Specification** in the grid to the right and click the ellipses (…) to the right of the property.

Now, you will be able to see relationship of that table with other tables.